# wso2 IS as KM can't use SCIM

Tags: wso2, scim, wso2-identity-server

I installed a IS as KM (v3.0.0) with mysql database user store. I'm trying to use the SCIM api to create a user but I'm getting a 302 redirection.

Using a browser to access https://is-as-km:9443/wso2/scim/Users/me returns "Error 405 - Method Not Allowed".

In both cases I'm not getting any messages in wso2carbon.log to indicate what happened.

here is my curl to create a user

curl -v -k --user admin:admin --data '{"schemas":[],"name":{"familyName":"gunasinghe","givenName":"hasinitg"},"userName":"hasinitg@home.com","password":"hasinitg","emails":[{"primary":true,"value":"hasini@home.com","type":"home"}]}' --header "Content-Type:application/json" https://localhost:9443/wso2/scim/Users

which get redirected to the UI's login page

< HTTP/1.1 302

< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff

< X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block

< Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=D558CE2360A6D9790A2CE494569D406E; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly

< Set-Cookie: requestedURI=../../wso2/scim/Users; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly

< Location: https://localhost:9443/carbon/admin/login.jsp

< Content-Length: 0

< Date: Thu, 02 Apr 2020 16:18:02 GMT

< Server: WSO2 Carbon Server

I have included 
scim_enabled = true
in the deployment.toml under the user store section

I have also configured under Resident services provider -> Inbound Provisioning Configuration -> SCIM configuration to use the PRIMARY userstore (the only one configured)

What else should I check?

Answer (score 1):

By v3.0.0 did you mean the API Manager version? Respective IS-KM version should be v5.9.0 I believe.

However, this request URL `https://localhost:9443/wso2/scim/Users` is for a `SCIM1.1` request. Later versions of Identity Servers(KM) are compatible with `SCIM2.0` by default. If there's no special reason for you to go after the older version, please try the SCIM2 APIs as explained in this [documentation](https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/next/develop/scim2-rest-apis/#/Me%20Endpoint/createUserMe).

URL would be `https://localhost:9443/scim2/Me`

Comment: You are correct, I mean the api manager version. I've seen IS 5.9.0 with the default configuration of the user store connected to the embedded LDAP working with SCIM1.1. Anyway I tested SCIM2 on the IS as KM and the URL returns a blank page. I also tested with curl -k -X GET "https://localhost:9443/t/wso2/scim2/Me" -H  "accept: application/scim+json" -H  "authorization: Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=" and I'm getting authentication error. Does SCIM2 require a specific user? I have only the default admin user.